# How to redirect to another host from Filter?

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, httpresponse, servlet-filters

How to forward request from Filter to another URL and get the result back?

I'm using `Filter` and `HttpClient.execute()` method to forward the request. Is that way is the right way?

Here is the code:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
...
HttpRequestBase method = null;
URI uri = null;
if (isPost) {
    method = new HttpPost();
} else {
    method = new HttpGet();
}

uri = new URI(newUrl);    

Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

 while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String header = headerNames.nextElement();    
    method.setHeader(header, request.getHeader(header));    
}
method.setURI(uri);

HttpResponse downstreamResponse = httpClient.execute(method);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
downstreamResponse.getEntity().writeTo(baos);
OutputStream responseStream = response.getOutputStream();
responseStream.write(responseBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain)
```

you are getting a `ServletResponse`

so you can cast it to a `HttpServletResponse`

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) res;
httpResponse.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
```

Comment: I've added code to the question. the thing is that redirect is to other hosts. and the requests is SOAP requests.

Comment: so it is not forwarding, it is logging?

Comment: No. The problem is that i need to redirect the request to other url based on some conditions from SOAP message. so i used filter.

Comment: sounds architecturally dodgy/slow